# How to reduce the spacing in chemical symbols?

Tags: spacing, chemistry, mathjax

Currently, if want to write a chemical symbol, for example, ${}^{239}Np$, this is what I type in: `{}^{239}Np`. The result:

[image: Np 239, looking bad]

But it looks bad, I feel as if the "N" and "p" should be closer, or a different font should have been used.

How could I make better looking chemical symbols? Currently I am using mainly the MathJax of the SE, but sometimes I use other TeX as well.

Comment: I don't know why my text code weren't processed as on other SE sites, maybe it is a localhost problem. I extended the question with a screenshot - if the mathjax works correctly by you, feel free to remove it.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! I think that a little more of an example might help.  For instance the packages you load, and the fonts you load could have an effect on your spacing.  Take a look at the guidelines set out for MWE's on this site for how much example to include in your example. _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Comment: @peterh see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously `Np` should be upright. Hence

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}


$^{239}\mathrm{Np}$


With tensor package:

$\tensor[^{239}]{\mathrm{Np}}{}$

But with both numbers not

$\tensor[^{239}_{93}]{\mathrm{Np}}{}$

but

$\tensor*[^{239}_{93}]{\mathrm{Np}}{}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If by “other TeX” you mean LaTeX then use a dedicated chemistry package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

\ch{^{239}Np} \\
\ch{^{239}_{93}Np} % or \ch{^{239}93Np}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{^{239}Np} \\
\ce{^{239}_{93}Np}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula , % or `mhchem'
  modules = {isotopes}
}

\begin{document}

\isotope*{Np} \\
\isotope{Np}

\end{document}
```

All three examples give

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could throw in a negative `kern` and that would close up some of the space.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
    ${}^{239}N\kern -1pt p$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use the `elements` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{elements}
\begin{document}

$^{239}$\elementsymbol{Neptunium}

The electron distribution 

of Neptunium is: 

\elconf{Np} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Element symbols should be typeset upright according to IUPAC recommendations

Comment: Additional information: the `chemmacros` module `isotopes` that I've used in my answer uses the `elements` package behind the scenes :)

Comment: The "man behind the mask" ...