# Superscript in upper left to denote isotope in LaTeX

Tags: chemistry, left-superscripts

I am trying to denote a <sup>28</sup>Si isotope. I used 
`$^{28}Si$`. In the output, the chemical symbol is in italics, also there is an unnecessary space between the symbol and the nucleon number.

How do I get the chemical symbol 'Si' in roman, and the superscript and symbol a bit closer? I will use this code to denote a label in a Python code graph.

Comment: Have you tried `${}^{28}$Si`?

Comment: I have a feeling this posting is a dupe, but I haven't found a suitable earlier posting yet.

Comment: @Mico You mean this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319325/isotopes-module-with-chemmacros

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm not sure how nobody has posted **[mhchem](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mhchem)**, the canonical chemistry package! Straight from [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mhchem), section "Isotopes":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

I have some \ce{^{227}_{90}Th+} lying around.

\end{document}
```

> [image: output]

(`\ce` stands for "chemical equation" and can be used in either math or text mode.)

If you're doing other stuff with chemistry, this is the package you want. Check out [the docs](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mhchem)!

Comment: Please clear your desk of this Thorium and bin it appropriately within the next 18.68 days.

Answer (score 18):

Smaller and lighter than `mhchem` is the [`isotope` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/isotope?lang=en).

Usage looks roughly like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{isotope}

\begin{document}
\isotope{Po} --- \isotope[56]{Fe} --- \isotope[13][6]{C}\\

$\isotope{n} + \isotope{H} \to \isotope{D} +
\gamma(2.2\,\mathrm{MeV})$ \\

$\isotope[13]{C} + \alpha(5.314\,\mathrm{MeV}) \to
\isotope[16]{O}^{**} + n$
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: The output appears to be in math mode (font) though I haven't used one - can I change this to my preferred font?

Answer (score 6):

You may wish to define a macro to typeset isotopes, say,

```
\newcommand\isotope[2]{\textsuperscript{#2}#1}
```

Use the macro as follows: `\isotope{Si}{28}`.

This approach avoids the use of math mode and associated low-level solutions such as `${}^{28}$Si`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use any of the following:

1. `${}^{28}$Si`
2. `${}^{28}\mbox{Si}$`
3. `${}^{28}\text{Si}$`, you need to load `amstext` package.
4. `${}^{28}\mathrm{Si}$`
5. `${}^{28}{\rm Si}$`

Comment: You may wish to add a note that while the fifth method works with the "standard" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, and `book`), it generates a warning message with the KOMA-Script document classes and crashes with the `memoir` document class. Since other, perfectly valid and general, solution methods are available, it may not be a good idea to even present method 5.

Comment: Acceptable are 2. and 4. In 1. and partially 3. a logic of expression is lost. In 5. we have `\rm`, deprecated in LaTeX.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke 4 is probably how I'd do it for a one-off.  But the logic is already broken assuming you write `"I have a 4 Si wafers but only one of them is $^{28}\mathrm{Si}$"`

Comment: although method 3 may look attractive, if it happens to be embedded in a context that is in italic, the `Si` will also be set italic, which is wrong.  using one of the "chemistry" packages is really the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 4):

If  you can use additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}

More effective than
$^{28}\mathrm{Si}$

is (with tensor package):

$\tensor[^{28}]{\mathrm{Si}}{}$

\end{document}
```

Additional remarks are here: [How to reduce the spacing in chemical symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315475/how-to-reduce-the-spacing-in-chemical-symbols/315478#315478)