The best way to show the connection of isotopes to chemical molecules?
Is there a package that has been specially optimized for the notation of isotopes and chemical bonds?
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\chemdelta\isotope*{2,H}--\ch{H2O}
\end{document}


Or, is this the best way now?

Have a look here, which is in line wirh what I know from physics: https://preparatorychemistry.com/Bishop_Isotope_Notation.htm . The isotope package had some problems when I tried it last time, while its typesetting is easy to replicate. See e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322132/superscript-in-upper-left-to-denote-isotope-in-latex

mhchem includes this sort of functionality.

@MS-SPO They haven't -- for chemical bonds.

@karlh I used to use mhchem before switching to chemmacros, and now I have to switch back to mhchem again.

We talk about conventions and typesetting. Just for my understanding: Why do you put a delta in front? Why isn't \isotope{2,H}--\ch{H2O} sufficient?

@MS-SPO Because I think this key position seems to be unique to the subject of chemistry.

I tried to find examples. I‘ve seen, say Carbon atoms inside a molecule with exponents alpha, beta etc. I‘ve seen delta(13C/12C) or abreviated to express isotope ratios. Only I haven‘t seen a delta combined with a molecule as in your example. Is that notation a standard in chemistry? If so, where is it defined or used, to have a better understanding of the kind of typesetting you need to do? Thank you

@MS-SPO Thanks. I don't if you can download this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048969724030705?via%3Dihub, in which you will see a lot of such kind of symbols. It is very common to use this kind of symbols.

Thank, start to understand. Unfortunately your link asks to purchase the pdf, but this seems to be free showing similar examples: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-9326/abdcef/pdf // So what your example spells out is „the ratio of Deuterium to Hydrogen isotopes in the water molecule …“. Your example seems to typeset fine, so I wonder what you ask for? Would a \newcommand do it, like \iso{2}{H}{H2O} to simplify your inputs?

REMARK to bot: Still clarification phase, no discussion.

@MS-SPO I don't think it is the -- between isotope and chemical formula.

While there seems to be no such library, here is a way to both simplify and standardize text input using a set of self defined macros:

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % just to retrive the mentioned article

% ~~~ shorthand notations ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\iso[2]{\chemdelta\isotope*{#1}--\ch{#2}}% for OP's example
\newcommand\delt[1]{\chemdelta\ch{#1}}% mimicking the report

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
% ~~~ part 1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
From the OP's example, extended:\vspace{5mm}

Some text \chemdelta\isotope*{2,H}--\ch{H2O} and more text.
\bigskip

\isotope{2,H}--\ch{H2O}

Other \iso{2,H}{H2O} text

\hrule\bigskip


% ~~~ part 2 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

From Figure 1 in \url{https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-9326/abdcef/pdf}\bigskip

\dots 
\delt{NO3-} (i.e. \iso{15,N}{NO3-} vs 
\dots

\end{document}


Assuming your comment about -- asks about typesetting this horizontal bar/line/character, here are a few variants.
The key to understanding may be to perceive this line \chemdelta\isotope*{2,H}--\ch{H2O} consisting of 3 "text-objects", where by chance 2 of them are related to the chemmacros package:

\chemdelta\isotope*{2,H}
--
\ch{H2O}

So parameter #3 in this modified macro

\newcommand\isox[3]{\chemdelta\isotope*{#1}#3\ch{#2}}% #3 varies text in between

plays with it a little. Or in other words: typeset in between, what seems to be reasonable (and put it inside of a dedicated macro for consistent re-use). I don't see any guideline (on a very quick glance) in the IUPAC documents about the typesetting of dashes and spaces ... and this probably was out of scope when first released in 1978:

http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/BB-prs310305/CompleteDraft.pdf
section H: https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/


\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% ~~~ shorthand notations ~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\isox[3]{\chemdelta\isotope*{#1}#3\ch{#2}}% #3 varies text in between


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 \toprule
 Variant&Result&Comment\\
 \midrule
 just text&                 \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{justText}  &for reference\\
 \midrule
 dash&                      \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{-}         &trying some Latex dashes\\
 2-&                        \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{--}\\
 emdash&                    \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{---}\\
 with a tikz line&          \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{\tikz{\draw[red] (0,0) -- +(1,0);}}&going wild, needs a raisebox\\
 \midrule
 2- with unbreakable spaces&\isox{2,H}{H3O+}{\ --\ }        &trying some spaces\\
 with math mode&            \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{$-\quad$}\\
 with hspace&               \isox{2,H}{H3O+}{-\hspace{2pt}}\\
 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}

